# Algolia React instantsearch Map Zoom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, algolia

With React InstantSearch, I can’t seem to reach the map object to manipulate it.

The goal is to accomplish what this fiddle is demo’ing (the zoom in, zoom out functionnality):

https://jsfiddle.net/vh3s88mc/15/

i've tried to access it via the prototype but it doesn't seems to work ;

```
const map = window.google.maps.Map
map.prototype.setZoom(10)
```

i've also tried to use React.createRef() on the GeoSearch to access map but same result ;

```
const map = mapRef.current.props.google.maps.Map
const map = mapRef.current.props.google.maps.Map
```

Comment: I built a simple InstantSearch + Google Maps demo last year that includes scroll and zoom. It might be useful as a model?

https://codesandbox.io/s/github/chuckmeyer/covid-geosearch